# Is there something i can do for this to work?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

My problem is that i can't get the entry input from the fonction i created. If someone can help fast, that will be really useful!

There's my code :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Blumpy")
root.geometry("420x280")

l1 = Label(root, text="Blumpy",font="Impact", bg="Blue")
l1.pack()

def Window_2():
    newWindow = Toplevel()
    newWindow.title("Connect to Blumpy")

    l2 = Label(newWindow, text="Connect to Blumpy",font="Impact", bg="Blue")
    l2.pack()
    
    e1 = Entry(newWindow)
    e1.pack()
    
    b2 = Button(newWindow, text="Connect",command=verifCode)
    b2.pack()

def verifCode():
    getCode = e1.get()
    if getCode == "d2c4r13G3T8LUM9Y" :
        newWindow.destroy()

b1 = Button(root, text="Connect", command=Window_2)
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Comment: Does it work if the entry is in `root` rather than `newWindow`?

Comment: The variables `newWindow` and `e1` in `Window_2` are local variables.  You should be getting an error if `verifCode`, since it has no idea what these values are.  Try adding `global e1, newWindow` to `Window2`

Comment: Please use a title that describes your specific problem. Your title is too generic and could describe 90% of questions.

Comment: Run this from the command line and you'll see an exception, Add that to the question as it is an important detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your `verifCode` function is using variables (`e1`, `newWindow`) that are not defined in the context of the function.

Either use the global keyword or an inner function:

### Using global

In `Window_2()`, declare all variables as global that you are going to use later outside of the function's scope:

```
def Window_2():
    global newWindow
    global e1
    newWindow = Toplevel()
    newWindow.title("Connect to Blumpy")

    l2 = Label(newWindow, text="Connect to Blumpy",font="Impact", bg="Blue")
    l2.pack()

    e1 = Entry(newWindow)
    e1.pack()

    b2 = Button(newWindow, text="Connect",command=verifCode)
    b2.pack()
```

Now the variables `newWindow` and `e1` will be available in a global scope, which means the `verifCode` function can use them.

### Using an inner function

Move `verifCode` into `Window_2()`. For the button to be able to reference the function, it must be defined before the button is defined:

```
def Window_2():
    newWindow = Toplevel()
    newWindow.title("Connect to Blumpy")

    l2 = Label(newWindow, text="Connect to Blumpy",font="Impact", bg="Blue")
    l2.pack()

    e1 = Entry(newWindow)
    e1.pack()

    def verifCode():
        getCode = e1.get()
        if getCode == "d2c4r13G3T8LUM9Y" :
            newWindow.destroy()

    b2 = Button(newWindow, text="Connect",command=verifCode)
    b2.pack()
```

Now `e1` and `newWindow` will be available in the `verifCode` function because it is defined in the same scope as these variables.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The 'global' function is working well!

Answer (score 0):

Bad style in python is `from tkinter import *`. A variable created inside a function belongs to the *local scope* of that function, and can only be used inside that function. You missed also to define the variable of the entry widget at all - `e1_text = tk.StringVar()`:

Try this one:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Blumpy")
root.geometry("420x280")

l1 = tk.Label(root, text="Blumpy",font="Impact", bg="Blue")
l1.pack()

def Window_2():
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel()
    newWindow.title("Connect to Blumpy")
    
    def verifCode():
        getCode = e1_text.get()
        if getCode == "d2c4r13G3T8LUM9Y" :
            newWindow.quit()
            newWindow.destroy()

    l2 = tk.Label(newWindow, text="Connect to Blumpy",font="Impact", bg="Blue")
    l2.pack()
    
    e1_text = tk.StringVar()
    e1 = tk.Entry(newWindow, textvariable=e1_text)
    e1.pack()
    
    b2 = tk.Button(newWindow, text="Connect",command=verifCode)
    b2.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(root, text="Connect", command=Window_2)
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `e1 = tk.StringVar()` is useless and not necessary because `e1` is override by the line `e1 = tk.Entry(newWindow)`.  Also calling `newWindow.quit()` will terminate the application which may not be what OP wants.

Comment: @acw1668, you are right my failure is corrected now.